# Minimum steps to reach target by a Knight In Scala

Tags: interview-questions, matrix, scala, cache, chess

Given a chessboard of N size (square matrix), the position of Knight and position of a target, find out minimum steps (both count and exact steps) from start to target for a Knight.

If it is not possible to reach to the given position, return -1 as step count.

Here is my implementation in Scala (assuming N = 4 or 4X4 chess board):

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

object KnightMoves extends App {
  case class Pos(row: Int, col: Int)
  val Size = 4

  def calculateMoves(from: Pos, target: Pos ): (Int, Seq[Pos])= {
    val pendingPos = collection.mutable.Queue[Pos](from)
    val positionVisited = collection.mutable.HashMap[Pos, (Int, Seq[Pos])](from -> (0, Seq()))
    var targetReached = false

    while(pendingPos.nonEmpty && !targetReached) {
      val p = pendingPos.dequeue()
      possibleMoves(p) foreach { position =>
        if ( position == target) {
          targetReached = true
        } else if (!(positionVisited contains position)) {
          pendingPos enqueue position
        }
        positionVisited += position -> ((positionVisited(p)._1 + 1,(positionVisited(p)._2 ++ Seq(p))))
      }
    }
    if (targetReached) positionVisited(target) else (-1, Seq())
  }

  def isValidPos(position: Pos): Boolean =
    ((0 until Size) contains position.row) && ((0 until Size) contains position.col)

  def possibleMoves(position: Pos): List[Pos] =
    List(Pos(position.row - 2, position.col + 1),
        Pos(position.row - 2, position.col - 1),
        Pos(position.row + 2, position.col + 1),
        Pos(position.row + 2, position.col - 1),
        Pos(position.row - 1  , position.col + 2),
        Pos(position.row - 1  , position.col - 2),
        Pos(position.row + 1  , position.col + 2),
        Pos(position.row + 1  , position.col - 2)
    ) filter( pos => isValidPos(pos))

  println(calculateMoves(Pos(0,1),Pos(0,0)))
  println(calculateMoves(Pos(0,1),Pos(0,2)))
}
```

This program generates the following output for two test statements at bottom.

```
(3,ArrayBuffer(Pos(0,1), Pos(2,0), Pos(1,2)))
(3,ArrayBuffer(Pos(0,1), Pos(2,2), Pos(1,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the `isValidPos()` method looks to be clear and succinct, requiring only two tests to see if the passed position is on the board.

```
def isValidPos(position: Pos): Boolean =
  ((0 until Size) contains position.row) && ((0 until Size) contains position.col)
```

But it turns out that the `contains()` method on a `Range` is [a bit complicated](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/38cd84d976880eab16af17a44d186bbddcd554f2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L343) and most valid positions will have to pass around 10 `if` checks before the method returns `true`, so there are probably more efficient ways to get the same result.

But a bigger question is, can this be done without any mutable collections or variables?

One approach is to create a `Knight` class that holds all current valid board positions and the history of how each position was arrived at and then, when taking the next step, instead of modifying the `Knight` instance you create a new immutable `Knight` instance with all the new information built from the current (old) data.

```
type Cell = (Int,Int)

class Knight(dim :Int, history :Map[Cell,Cell], val cells :Set[Cell]) {
  def this(dim :Int, cell :Cell) = this(dim, Map(cell->(-1,-1)), Set(cell))

  def backtrack(cell :Cell) :List[Cell] =
    if (history(cell) == (-1,-1)) cell :: Nil
    else                          cell :: backtrack(history(cell))

  def next :Knight = (new Knight(dim, _:Map[Cell,Cell], _:Set[Cell])).tupled{
    cells.foldLeft((history, Set.empty[Cell])){
      case ((hMap,cSet),(x,y)) =>
        val newSet = Set((x-2, y-1), (x-2, y+1), (x-1, y-2), (x-1, y+2)
                        ,(x+1, y-2), (x+1, y+2), (x+2, y-1), (x+2, y+1)
                        ).filter{ case (a,b) =>
              a >= 0 && a < dim && b >= 0 && b < dim && !hMap.keySet((a,b))
                                }
        (hMap ++ newSet.map(_ -> (x,y)).toMap, cSet ++ newSet)
    }
  }
}

def knightMoves(boardSize :Int, knight :Cell, target :Cell) :List[Cell] = {
  def loop(k1 :Knight, k2 :Knight) :List[Cell] = {
    val met :Set[Cell] = k1.cells.intersect(k2.cells)
    if (met.nonEmpty) k1.backtrack(met.head).reverse ++
                      k2.backtrack(met.head).tail
    else if (k1.cells.isEmpty || k2.cells.isEmpty) Nil
    else if (k1.cells.size > k2.cells.size) loop(k1, k2.next)
    else                                    loop(k1.next, k2)
  }
  loop(new Knight(boardSize, knight), new Knight(boardSize, target))
}

knightMoves(3,(0,1),(1,1))    //res0: List[Cell] = List()
knightMoves(14,(0,1),(10,12)) //res1: List[Cell] = List((0,1), (2,2), (4,3), (6,4), (7,6), (8,8), (9,10), (10,12))
```

Some efficiency is obtained here by making the target position a `Knight` instance as well. That way they can "move" toward each other and, as soon as they intersect, a path from one to the other is found.